# Does ITextSharp support CSS 'border-bottom' shorthand property

Tags: css, pdf, xhtml, itext, html-table

When using the XMLWorker in ITextSharp 5.5.1 to convert XHTML to a PDF. The border-bottom shorthand CSS property does not work. If I specify each property individually I get the desired results but the XHTML I am working with already has all the CSS written using this shorthand property.

Is there a workaround for this or will this be supported soon?

Here is the desired result...

[image: Good CSS]

Here is what it renders as...

[image: Good CSS]

The HTML for reference

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            td { border-bottom: 1px solid black; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>This is some text in a paragraph</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The ITextSharp code for reference

```
using (var document = new Document())
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
using (var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream))
using (var stringReader = new StringReader(html))
{
    document.Open();
    XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(pdfWriter, document, stringReader);
    document.Close();

    return memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I can't help you but I stepped through the debugger and am definitely see what you're seeing. `border-bottom: 1px solid black;` goes down one path and `border: 1px solid black;` goes down a completely different path.